# System.Exception in InitializeComponent()?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a bizarre problem that is causing us problems.

We have a simple C# Wpf UserControl. Its a progress bar - nothing fancy - just a border that changes size depending on bindings to Value and MaxValue. It works fine 99% of the time and we use it in a dozen or so places in out code - including the splash screen.

It always works fine in the splash screen - so it always loads and works in our app.

The problem is that sometimes (and we can't predict or understand when) the InitializeComponent() call in the progress bar constructor throws a System.Exception. Looking into the progressbar.g.cs file created during compile (obj/Debug folder) I can see that the exception is thrown because the progressbar.xaml file is not found. I have not, of course, changed any code in the g.cs file and I haven't done anything fancy in this UserControl at all.

`System.Exception: The component 'MyProject.ControlLibrary.ProgressBar' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/MyProject.ControlLibrary;component/progressbar.xaml'.
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at MyProject.ControlLibrary.ProgressBar.InitializeComponent() in d:\Projectfolder\MyProject.ControlLibrary\ProgressBar.xaml:line 1
   at MyProject.ControlLibrary.ProgressBar..ctor() in D:\projectfolder\MyProject.ControlLibrary\ProgressBar.xaml.cs:line 26
   at ProjectName.UI.VideoViewer..ctor() in D:\projectfolder\UI\VideoViewer.xaml.cs:line 26
Source: PresentationFramework`

I don't understand why the progressbar.xaml resource would go missing sometimes, especially given that it always works fine at least once when the app is run.

The UserControl is contained in a project called MyProject.ControlLibrary.dll. This project seems to be configured correctly as it contains other usercontrols which don't show any problems - except from one other similar UserControl which has identical problems.

I have run out of ideas on this - so any suggestions would be helpful. I am using VisualStudio 2008 and .net 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *may* have solved this - I'll explain the problem here in case someone else runs into it.

One section of our code dynamically loads plugins from a plugins folder. To do this, it does Assembly.LoadFile(filename) for all the .dll files in the plugins folder.

It checks to see if the dll implements our plugins interface; if it does, it loads it, if not, it doesn't. Our plugin interfaces are contained in a file called MyProject.Interfaces.dll and this file, along with MyProject.ControlLibrary.dll are also in the plugin's folder.

So, the code sometimes calls Assembly.LoadFile on MyProject.ControlLibrary.dll twice as it cycles through the dlls in the plugins folder. It seems that following this second LoadFile, the xaml resources become lost. When I prevent this second load, it seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

[This Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e92390eb-bbfa-42fb-baa9-2286444c0dca/)  seems to be the best discussion of the problem.  The short answer suggests that your usercontrol might have been loaded into two different assemblies.  The long answer is that there are many people who have run into the bug and it's not clear if they found a consistent resolution/work-around.  One person has said that MS may have fixed the problem in 4.0

Comment: Thanks for that. A little disheartening.

Answer (score 0):

I too want to add my bit of information on this topic.

I too am using a plugin-wise application, each Assembly is loaded in its own AppDomain, but first I load the assembly to see if it is and what class I need to instantiate.

For that I used to use `Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(file));`. If I did this before instantiating the window then the `InitializeComponent()` would throw me the errors.

If I first instantiate the window and then load the assemblies everything works fine.
Though the Window can be opened and closed at any time, thus most of the time those assemblies have been loaded.

What I did to fix this problem is first create a seperate AppDomain, and then load the assemblies within that appdomain using: Assembly asm = `PrivateAssemblyLoader.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(file));`

That way the current AppDomain will not be hindered by the loaded assemblies.

(In my plugin app thing I look for all .exe and .dll files within the executing directory, thus it can also load itself.)